# want to make custom dropdown in first level in wordpress with menu code, but am not getting where to start?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image: this is my dropdown for wordpress]here is code what I want to achieve by WordPress custom dropdown but I can't, can anyone tell me how can I do that, and other menu items should be normal and simple

```
[![<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="products.html">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="images/dropdown-img.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <span class="title">Cable &amp;<br> Cable Accessories</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown" href="service.html">Service</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    DEMO
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    DEMO
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="brands.html">Contact</a>
    </li>

</ul>][1]][1]
```

Comment: By custom dropdown, you're talking about the main navigation menu? For this purpose, there are several menu plugins that can achieve a highly customizable main navigation menus. Before you start implementing a highly complex customizable menu solution yourself, why not check out if for example "Max Mega Menu" offers what you want? The 6-column layout on your screenshot should be possible for one specific main menu point.

Comment: Hi Damocles, 

thanks for your reply, my custom menu design can't be achieved by Max mega menu, want to do this by custom code.

if you have any code or reference can you please share with me